# Jquery: draggable item not bringing to front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have some html markup:

```
<body>
    ...
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="someDiv">...</div>
        <div id="content">...</div>
    </div>
    ...
</body>
```

And I have partial html page with markup like this:

  @foreach(var item in Model.Items)
          {
  }

This partial page I am loading into the main page into div with id="content". I am using jquery:

```
ajax.partial(
            Url.Action("Action", "Controller"),
            {},
            function (data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
                makeDraggable();
            },
            function () {
                alert('error!');
            }
        );
```

I am using asp.net mvc, and my Controller has Action that returns all needed data in Model.
My method makeDraggable() makes "a" items which have class "m-item" draggable:

```
makeDraggable() {
    $('.m-item').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        opacity: 0.4,
        stack: $('.m-item')
    });
}
```

I added mCustomScrollbar to div with id="partialContainer".

```
if ($('#content').data().mCS_Init == undefined) {
            $('#partialContainer').mCustomScrollbar({
                scrollInertia: 0,
                mouseWheel: "auto",
                scrollButtons: {
                    enable: true
                },
                advanced: {
                    updateOnContentResize: true
                }
            });
        }
```

Dragging works but "a" elements are not bringing to front! The problem is with using mCustomScrollbar and draggable option together. When I get rid of scrollBar it works fine (elements are bringing to front). But I need scrollBar! What should I do?

Comment: Add `zIndex: 9999` to your `.draggable` options.

Comment: I tried but this doesn't help.